# jqgrid not loading properly under jquery-ui tabs if the tab is not active

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jquery-ui tabs and i have 3 tabs. in each tab i will have a jqgrid(with freeze column feature) which will load on selecting that tab. Jqgrid contacts server to fetch colmodel and data.

While the jqgrid server communication ajax call is going on, if i try to navigate to other tab, then the grid is not loading properly(especially freeze column feature is not working) in the previously opened tab.

I believe as the content of the tab gets hidden whenever i navigate to other tab, this is causing the problem.

Is there any solution to get rid of this problem.
Even though i navigate to other tab, the jqgrid should load properly..

i have used the following link provided by oleg to achieve freeze column feature.
http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FrozenColumnsAndFilterToggle.htm

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem which might help to somebody..
The solution is i found on jquery ui-tabs homepage ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ ) only

```
Any component that requires some dimensional computation for its initialization won't work in a hidden tab, because the tab panel itself is hidden via display: none so that any elements inside won't report their actual width and height (0 in most browsers).

There's an easy workaround. Use the off-left technique for hiding inactive tab panels. E.g. in your style sheet replace the rule for the class selector ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide" with

.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'am using this script. try this:

```
$('.jquery_tabs').tabs({
    activate:function(event,ui){
        ui.newPanel.find('table.ui-jqgrid-btable').each(function(){
            var $table=$(this);
            if($table.is(':visible') && $table.jqGrid('getGridParam','autowidth')){
                var $parent=$table.closest('.ui-jqgrid').parent();
                $table.jqGrid('setGridWidth',$parent.width());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've have the same problem if I put a jqGrid inside a div styled with "display: none" I suspect that jqGrid has code that sizes itself to the container that it is in based on the DOM properties that it is able to read from the container. It probably isn't able to read and height and width data from the tabs.

Try creating the grids inside a visible DOM element, and then use jQuery to move the containers into your tabs.

Also, it might help with your debugging if you take the tabs out of the equation. Experiment with creating a jqGrid into a hidden div, and see how it behaves.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to reply, but I faced the same problem and solved it finally, I loaded the tabs at first before loading the grid and made all the tabs visible true. See the below code snippet for reference.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    BindAllData();
});

var BindAllData = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../../Handler/GetAllBillingData.ashx',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
            $("div.ui-tabs-panel").show();
            // jqgrid binding logic.

        },
        error: function (errorText) {
            alert("Wwoops something went wrong !");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
<style>
        .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
            position: absolute;
            left: -10000px;
        }
</style>
```

it works for me